# How to replace a character to another in a column of a text file using awk command in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file which looks a bit like

```
column1    column2    column3
1          45n8       005
2          125n05     007
3          002n012    009
```

How can I use awk to replace the 'n' in column2 with a '.' where the output will look like this:

```
column1    column2    column3
1          45.8       005
2          125.05     007
3          002.012    009
```

my attempt at this is `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";}{gsub("n",".",$2);print}' file1.txt>file2.txt` and its giving me a 'command not found' error

Comment: i have tried gsub() which is simple and i think is working great but them im saving the results to another file by doing file1.txt>file2.txt at the end of awk and there its giving me an error :
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> file1. <<< txt
awk: bailing out at source line 1

Comment: Please include your code and the error message in your question. Without an attempt to solve the problem yourself, the question is likely to get voted down.

Comment: i just did. i resolved that error but a new one is coming up

Comment: For me your code works fine but you have to be aware that the `n` in `column2` is also replaced. You should do the substitutions only for lines greater than 1 `NR>1` (see Kents answer). I guess you mistyped something in your shell.

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to replace all `n` in a row, but only the col2, so you could:

```
awk 'NR>1{sub(/n/,".",$2)}7' file
```

If you want the output format looks better:

```
awk 'NR>1{sub(/n/,".",$2)}7' file|column -t
```

Comment: the first one worked!. so if i want to save that in another file how would the last part of your second code be? file.txt|column -t >file2.txt ?

Comment: `awk 'NR>1{sub(/n/,".",$2)}7' file1.txt | column -t > file2.txt`

Comment: @Kent What is the 7 for?

Comment: and what if i want to separate the columns with a comma not a '-t'

Comment: apparently removing the 7 will not print on the new file but no errors given.

Comment: @rambo column -t inserts a tab right? how can i insert a space instead?

Comment: Just look it up `man column`. It prints the result as a table. You can just ditch it and use the output field seperator of awk like you did in your question.

Comment: @john.s the `7` non-zero number will let awk start the default action: `print`

Comment: so you can write any non zero number or you can write print ?

Comment: @john.s why not give it a try? ;)